# Sanctum Guard Error With using Spatie Package in laravel

Tags: laravel, guard, laravel-sanctum, spatie-activitylog

I receive a Sanctum guard error when I try to find a specific Role_id or Permission_id using a Spatie package in Laravel. It was working fine normally when I try to get all roles or permissions but it make an error only when I try to search for a specific id using Sanctum.

**Controller**

```
public function create()
{
    $role = Role::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get();
    $role_user = Role::findById(3);


    return response([
        'status' => true,
        'role' => $role,
        'role_user' => $role_user
    ], 200);
}
```

Note: it works when I changed the guard manually in db from web to sanctum.

I am using Laravel 10. I have Installed Sanctum for Rest Apis, Spatie for ACL. basically it works fine but it give an error when i try to find specific role or permision by id.

i have tried change my guard in user but it not work, i tried to change guard manually in db for checking it was working but it's not proper good thing to do that.

Comment: what error ... ?

Comment: what error? Changing the quard in the db is not a good choice, have you defined a permissions?

Comment: permission is defined, it works with the web guard but not work with the sanctum

Answer (score 0):

Basically, It is a problem with the `Sanctum guard`. The `Sanctum provider` configures its provider to `null`.

###### Solution

go to `config/auth.php` and add `sanctum guard` into the `guards` array like the example snippet given below:

```
'guards' => [
        'sanctum' => [
            'driver' => 'sanctum',
            'provider' => 'users'
        ]
    ],
```

> **Note**: Don't remove `web` guard from `guards array`.

For more details related to this error please visit following [Github Issue](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission/issues/1540).

I hope that will fix your problem.